Security server has no valid authentication certificate (xroad security service)
i try to register subsystem. but the result still no valid authentication certificate, the CA server are working nomally. anyone know to solution please help me. thank you.
Security Server Log
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)   
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
2024-04-24T05:01:58.148Z [https-jsse-nio-4000-exec-1] correlation-id:[6628924656274799b298e0c2d366e568] ERROR o.n.x.s.r.s.ManagementRequestSenderService - Sending management request failed
ee.ria.xroad.common.CodedException$Fault: Server.ClientProxy.SslAuthenticationFailed: Security server has no valid authentication certificate
        at ee.ria.xroad.common.CodedException.fromFault(CodedException.java:141)
        at ee.ria.xroad.common.message.SoapFault.toCodedException(SoapFault.java:130)
        at org.niis.xroad.common.managementrequest.ManagementRequestSender.getResponse(ManagementRequestSender.java:272)
        at org.niis.xroad.common.managementrequest.ManagementRequestSender.send(ManagementRequestSender.java:221)
        at org.niis.xroad.common.managementrequest.ManagementRequestSender.sendClientRegRequest(ManagementRequestSender.java:153)
        at org.niis.xroad.securityserver.restapi.service.ManagementRequestSenderService.sendClientRegisterRequest(ManagementRequestSenderService.java:137)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
        at org.niis.xroad.securityserver.restapi.service.ManagementRequestSenderService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.sendClientRegisterRequest(<generated>)
        at org.niis.xroad.securityserver.restapi.service.ClientService.registerClient(ClientService.java:487)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
        at org.niis.xroad.securityserver.restapi.service.ClientService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.registerClient(<generated>)
        at org.niis.xroad.securityserver.restapi.openapi.ClientsApiController.registerClient(ClientsApiController.java:543)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor172.invoke(Unknown Source)

Diagnostics
please help to solve thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
